# VueJS build and Elastic Beanstalk environment variables

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vuejs2, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm quite new to programming in AWS so I will do my best to explain my problem as thoroughly as possible.

My goal is to store an API (private) key as an environment variable on Elastic Beanstalk, for security purposes. My stack is NodeJS + Express + VueJS

---

**Local setup**

Locally I've created a **.env.local** file in the root folder with a `VUE_APP_TEST=Test is working locally` parameter. The VUE_APP_ part is needed as I want to call on this parameter from my vue app.
*After running a build*, I can call my parameter with NodeJS using the following code:

`var testparam = process.env.VUE_APP_TEST || "Test is not working"`

Which makes `testparam` equal to  `"Test is working locally"` in string format.
So far, so good!

---

**Elastic Beanstalk setup**

Following [this information from AWS's docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html) (under Configuring environment properties) I set the same variable as follows: [aws environment variable declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB0zc.png). As explained in the  AWS docs, the code for running the parameter is the same:

`var testparam = process.env.VUE_APP_TEST || "Test is not working"`

Only this time I expect the result to be `"Test is working on aws"`. However, the same `"Test is working locally"` appears.

I cannot get it to work and it looks to me like a really trivial problem. Can anyone help me? I've spent an entire day on this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is vue.js served from express or is it a SPA?

Comment: And can post a screen shot with the env var set in EBS.

Comment: the VueJS is served from express, the screen shot of the env var set in EBS is in the question (under the lin "aws environment variable declaration")